# Problems with notrend_test

Tags: r, trend

On the following data set, when I use the `notrend_test()` function of the `funtimes` package, I get the message

> Error in notrend_test(female_trend$Female_percent) : set a proper
> window." or "Error in notrend_test(female_trend$Female_numbers, test =
> "WAVK") :    set a proper window.

Here is the data set.

```
female_trend <- structure(list(Year = 2011:2020, Female = c(0.3793, 0.4082, 0.3333, 
0.1803, 0.2989, 0.4211, 0.3333, 0.3421, 0.2841, 0.2976), Female_percent = c(37.93, 
40.82, 33.33, 18.03, 29.89, 42.11, 33.33, 34.21, 28.41, 29.76
), Female_numbers = c(22L, 20L, 20L, 11L, 26L, 41L, 33L, 26L, 
25L, 25L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Code

```
library(funtimes)
notrend_test(female_trend$Female_percent)
notrend_test(female_trend$Female_numbers, test = "WAVK")
```

Session info

```
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_India.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_India.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_India.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=English_India.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] funtimes_8.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_4.1.0    cli_2.5.0         tools_4.1.0       withr_2.4.2       Rcpp_1.0.6       
 [6] FNN_1.1.3         rbibutils_2.2.3   boot_1.3-28       dbscan_1.1-8      Rdpack_2.1.2     
[11] Jmisc_0.3.1       sessioninfo_1.1.1 Kendall_2.2
```

Comment: Your time series is too short. Try with `notrend_test(rnorm(10))` and then `notrend_test(rnorm(30))`. In the first case the command returns the `set a proper window` message. In the second, it works.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, you mean to say the number of variables isn't enough? And the test is underpowered?

Comment: I mean that `notrend_test` needs a series with a length >= 30.

Comment: Okay, but my data has only 10 variables and I need to do a trend test. Would it be possible for you to suggest an alternative?

Comment: Try using the `trend` package. For example `cs.test(female_trend$Female)`.